# Pointer Variable to Locate the zero in the array

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a code that tries to scan over an array for '0' using a pointer variable and then setting the address to that of the space in the array that has '0' in it. Unfortunately, my program is returning 10 as the value and 0 as an index. I would really appreciate any input to help me, and I'm trying to do this without changing main, so I dont think the following code is possible.

```
int* zerofinder(int array[], int q)
{
int* p = null;    /// default value if there isn't a 0 in the array at 
all
for (int k = q - 1; k >= 0; k--)
{
if (arr[k] == 0)      // found an element whose value is 0
{
    p = arr[k];     // change the value of p
    break;           // stop looping and return
}
}
return p;
}
```

Instead I think I have to use

```
void zerofinder(int array[], int x, int* p); function to change the pointer?
```

Comment: *edit made to clear up confusing variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the pointer by value.

Then you change where the pointer points to but that only modifies the local copy. It does not change the value of the pointer in the calling function.

You can resolve the problem using one of the following two approaches.

1. Pass the pointer by reference.

   ```
   void findLastZero(int arr[], int n, int*& p);
   ```
2. Return the pointer from the function.

   ```
   int* findLastZero(int arr[], int n);
   ```

   This will change how you call the function. Instead of using:

   ```
   int* ptr;
   ptr = &nums[0];
   findLastZero(nums, 6, ptr);
   ```

   you can use:

   ```
   int* ptr = findLastZero(nums, 6);
   ```

Comment: Ah okay, I understand now, thank you. It seems that I was merely changing the copy, and not the real one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't *return* the value you want from the function

```
int* findLastZero(int arr[], int n)
{
int* p = nullptr;    /// default value if there isn't a 0 in the array at all
for (int k = n - 1; k >= 0; k--)
{
    if (arr[k] == 0)      // found an element whose value is 0
    {
        p = &arr[k];     // change the value of p
        break;           // stop looping and return
    }
}
return p;
}
```

and

```
ptr = findLastZero(nums, 6);
```

Sometimes newbies think that pointers are something special, but pointers are values too, and obey the usual C++ rules about pass-by-value. If you pass a pointer to a function then changing the value of that pointer inside the function has no effect on the value outside the function, just like any other type.

Comment: Ah, I see. So is there no way to go about using a void function to solve this problem? Because, I was told that the main function can not be changed like you suggested it should change here.

Comment: You could use a void function if you pass the pointer by reference `void findLastZero(int arr[], int n, int*& p)`, but in general I'd prefer to return the value than pass by reference.

Comment: In fact there is no need to pass the pointer to the function at all, see edit.

Comment: Ah thank you so much, I was told to do this without changing the main, so it seems like making it a pass by reference to the void is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a homework / test / quiz.

The answer to this quiz is: this can't be done without changing the `main` function.

### Why?

As others have already told you, you need to change the `findLastZero` signature, either changing the `p` parameter type as `int*&` or `int**`, or return an `int*` from the function.
If you don't change the `findLastZero` signature (and the `main`), the `findLastZero` function has no way to change the outer `ptr` variable.